# Why print a variable before declaring it can print out 0?

Tags: swift

I'm new in Swift. I learned that in Swift, a variable must be used after declaring it. But why variable can be used in `print statement` before declaring it and has 0 as its initial value?
[image]

Comment: Playgrounds are somewhat special. This would not compile in a real Xcode project.

Comment: @MartinR It would work in the main.swift in a macOS command line tool project too. I think the difference is whether the file is the special "main" file that gets executed line by line, not whether it's playground or not.

Comment: [This page](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=7) from 2014 says completely the opposite to we observe now - "Code within a playground file is order-dependent, run in top-down lexical order. For example, you can’t use a type before you define it." I can't find a more recent page saying that they changed it to the current behaviour...

Comment: Here is a bug report where declaring a variable before usage results in a crash: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-13905. Another “strange” behavior in main: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1804

Comment: I meant “using  a variable before declaring it” ...

Comment: @Sweeper: You are right, it compiles in main.swift. I *think* that is because variables declared at the file scope are global variables, but I am not sure. In any case, there are some bug reports about this.

Comment: And `print(a) ; let a = 1 ; print(a)` prints "0" and "1" even for a *constant*! That must be a bug.

Comment: To answer the question, no you do _not_ need to print a variable before you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

How can you get an updated value when you print it before initializing a new value.
You will have to print it after initializing a new value like the below code

```
var iniValue: Int = 1
Print(iniValue)
```

[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up6cK.png)

Comment: Why not just report an error but print out 0?

Comment: I have edited my answer with screenshot please check it
You have declared int value so you will get value 0. if you will declare a string you will get a blank string value. you have already declared the Int variable so by default you get the 0 value.